# Relativistic species now different from photons and neutrinos?

Tags: cosmology

Beyond photons and neutrinos (I give up the graviton at the moment), how do we know there is no further relativistic species contributing to the energy density? How is that measured?

Comment: Those are, I believe, classified as "hot dark matter"; searches are ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

Hot dark matter is a theoretical form of dark matter which consists of particles that travel with ultrarelativistic speeds.

There are basically two types of dark matter, hot and cold, and it refers to the size of the WIMP particles. Cold dark matter consists of particles with greater size (bigger mass), and they move slower. Hot dark matter consists of particles that have lower mass, and travel faster, at ultrarelativistic speeds.

Comment: Axions included?

Comment: The axion (/ˈæksiɒn/) is a hypothetical elementary particle postulated by the Peccei–Quinn theory in 1977 to resolve the strong CP problem in quantum chromodynamics (QCD). If axions exist and have low mass within a specific range, they are of interest as a possible component of cold dark matter.

Comment: Axions are cold dark matter, so they are slow.